# exclude some pattern in GNU parallel

Tags: tcsh, gnu-parallel

I want to use parallel to implement some files in one directory,

right now I have some tasks,

1, I want to skip some files, for example,

```
parallel -j 16 'zcat {} > {.}.unpacked' ::: *.gz
```

But for this I want to exclude some files with some pattern when operating this command. How can I implement this?

2, When some jobs when operating files are exited with error, how can I skip this status and continue operate other files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are a bit vague on what you want to exclude, but say you want to process all gzipped files except those starting with the letter `a`:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -iname "*.gz" ! -iname "a*" -print0 | parallel -0 'zcat {} > {.}.unpacked'
```

Regarding your second question, it is the default behaviour of **GNU Parallel** to continue after errors, so you shouldn't need to do anything explicitly. If you want to change it, look at the `--halt` option:

> --halt now,fail=1     exit when the first job fails. Kill running jobs.
>
> --halt soon,fail=3    exit when 3 jobs fail, but wait for running jobs to complete.
>
> --halt soon,fail=3%   exit when 3% of the jobs have failed, but wait for running jobs to complete.
>
> --halt now,success=1  exit when a job succeeds. Kill running jobs.
>
> --halt soon,success=3 exit when 3 jobs succeeds, but wait for running jobs to complete.
>
> --halt now,success=3% exit when 3% of the jobs have succeeded. Kill running jobs.
>
> --halt now,done=1     exit when one of the jobs finishes. Kill running jobs.
>
> --halt soon,done=3    exit when 3 jobs finishes, but wait for running jobs to complete.
>
> --halt now,done=3%    exit when 3% of the jobs have finished. Kill running jobs.

Comment: Thanks! After changing to this, I meet another problem,  "parallel: Error: Output is incomplete. Cannot append to buffer file in /proj/0/tmpfiles. Is the disk full?" However I still have a lot of workspaces in this directory. Is there some guide to fix this error? I already add --tmpdir /proj/0/tmpfiles and --compress in the commandline.

Comment: I'm not sure about that error. I would try it with fewer processes at a time by soecifying a smaller value for `-j` and see if that helps. Else ask a new question about the error - questions are free. Good luck.

Comment: @yewei In this case you probably do not care about the output, so you can use `-u`, which does not buffer on disk.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use `find`, you can use `skip()`:

```
parallel -j 16 'zcat {= /mypattern/ and skip() =} > {.}.unpacked' ::: *.gz
```

`/mypattern/` can be any Perl code.